# Can I set up zotero to download arxiv vanity when I download a paper from arxiv?

Tags: publications, reference-managers, tools

When I add a paper from arXiv to my zotero, it will download the arxiv paper along with all the details. I was wondering if there is some way to get it to also download the corresponding arxiv vanity html file.

I would imagine there is some script somewhere in the installation for each website, but I was wondering if its possible to easily modify these scripts from the interface, or if I'd have to dig into whatever is in these scripts?

Answer (score 0):

On your browser with Zotero connector installed, select the option to [**save with snapshot**](https://www.zotero.org/support/adding_items_to_zotero).

- right-clicking on the Zotero save button
- choose “Save to Zotero (Web Page with/without Snapshot)”.
  PS: you can enable '*automatically take snapshots*' downloading in Zotero preference (General Tab).

NB: Once arXiv Vanity retrieved the html of the arXiv paper (using the arXiv URL), what you have is '*normal webpage*' like any other.

> I was wondering if there is some way to get it to also download the corresponding arxiv vanity html file.

1. Use the Zotero's [save with snapshot option](https://www.zotero.org/support/adding_items_to_zotero) explained here.
   PS: This might be a two-step approach because arXiv-Vanity seemly uses two div to separate the top 'header' linking to arXiv and the rendered HTML in the bottom.
   PS: For completeness, unlike arXiv-Vanity, Zotero does not get the pdf from [Academus](https://academ.us/article/1406.1559/#) and [ar5iv](https://ar5iv.labs.arxiv.org/), both of which renders the arXiv as HTML.
2. Ask in the [Zotero's forum](https://forums.zotero.org/discussions). You might get a plugin or feature add or a workaround.
3. Write a [Zotero plugin to automate the process](https://www.zotero.org/support/plugins).

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that either I have to move through the menus to download the webpage (without downloading the arxiv paper/metadata) or if I just click it then it downloads the arxiv paper and snapshots the arxiv.org site instead of the arxiv-vanity site

Comment: Just to be on the same page, by ... *either I have to* ... are you assuming (without trying) or are you saying what you've tried by following *the answer*.

Comment: Zotero has a 'guide' on saving with snapshots. I just realised I didn't linked it to a phrase in my answer. I'll edit accordingly. Apologies for that.

Comment: I've tried, and when I tried I could only wave the web page with a snapshot, which seems to only store the URL of Arxiv-vanity, or I could just click save in which case it scrapes the data from the original arxiv. What I wanted was to just click the button (ideally on arxiv) and pull both the arxiv and the arxiv vanity pages into my downloads. I've found out that all of that is done by the translators and the arxiv ones look simple enough to understand how they work, so I will either dig into them, or look at writing a plugin to automate it in a more partitioned manner.